# how to solve lazy loading?

Tags: android

I am working android application.I have store 1000 values in database.when i retrieve the data from database,it's take more time to retrieve.how can i solve this problem.help me.........

Answer (score 0):

hi for this u display the rotating progress bar befor u display the date
use the below link [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057502/display-the-rotating-progress-before-display-the-data)

and [link text](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog)